# What does this schematic symbol mean (similar to solder bridge)?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, schematics

this symbol is similar to **solder bridge**, but there is a connection on both end.

what does this symbol mean, and what is the equivalent pcb for this symbol

[image]

Comment: The PCB footprint is pretty much what the circuit symbol is (except for the dots).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It really is a solder bridge, with a separate trace connection as well. The trace can be cut if needed, and then the solder bridge can be used to rejoin the connection if circumstances change.